# INNER JOIN two temp table no respond in postgresql usibn python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-2.7

I have run a query which inner join two temp table in postgresql using python to find a radio parameter different. Also I have csv file which increased the table name and column name. I use pandas to read the csv and query the postgreqsql several times and insert the result to a cell call comparsion.cccheck_table_cell.

This is my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
import csv
import psycopg2
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd


today=datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
yesterday=datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(2), '%Y- 
%m-%d')
i=0
abc=[]
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="xxx", 
    database="parameter",
    user="xxx",
    password="xxx",
    port="xxx"
)
abc =pd.read_csv(
    'xxxx/create_comp/164/cell_table.csv',
    header=None, index_col=False
)
table="insert into comparsion.cccheck_table_cell SELECT a.date as 
date,a.ne_name as ne_name,a.local_cell_id,'"+abc.iloc[i,1]+"' as 
parameter,a." + abc.iloc[i,1] + " as today_parameter,\
b." + abc.iloc[i,1] + " as yesterday_parameter FROM (select * from 
radio_parameter." + abc.iloc[i,0] + " \
where date='" + today + "')a INNER JOIN (select * from 
radio_parameter." + abc.iloc[i,0] + " where date='" + yesterday +
"')b ON a.ne_name = b.ne_name and a.local_cell_id=b.local_cell_id WHERE 
a." + abc.iloc[i,1] + " != b." + abc.iloc[i,1] + ";"
print(table)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(table)


cursor.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print('done_1')
```

For troubleshoot, I have print the query when execute one times. But I find the query no responds and no error found if I inner join two temp table.

Is anyone have these experience when execute the query which no respond but no error? Is the problem related to server or database loading problem?(my database is about 24GB)

Comment: what does the query look like?

Answer (score 0):

About your *SQL* statement :

- First of all, do you have a schema called `radio_parameter` and does
  your query have access to that schema..?
- literal derived from variable `abc.iloc[i,1]` has prefixes as `a.` or
  `b.`. In this case make sure the column name derived from that
  parameter is right for both tables aliased as `a` or `b`.

  *OR*

  literal derived from variable `abc.iloc[i,1]` has no prefix at one
  location which may cause ambiguity.
- some backslash (`\`) characters are seen in the *SQL*, are you sure
  that usage is right.

Comment: 1. yes, I am sure the schema existed 2. a and b is alise 3. (\) is not affect the querry.

Comment: @EdwinCheng ok, what do you think about ambiguity ?